# ImageMagick With HEIC Extension Issue in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, imagick, heic

I need to integrate HEIC extension in ImageMagick. I am using Amazon Linux 2 server. I have tried to install ImageMagick as mentioned in their documentation:
https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

The ImageMagick gets installed with the latest version but HEIC extension is not enabled.

I have tried configuring it as follows but it also didn't work.

`./configure --with-heic=yes`

I am using Amazon Linux 2 server, Apache as web server, and PHP 7.4.

Can anyone please help to have it enabled?

Comment: You need to install the libheif delegate library before compiling Imagemagick and tell Imagemagick to use it. See https://github.com/strukturag/libheif

Comment: I did. Still HEIC is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know much about installing on Linux let alone Amazon.  Mostly you have to install all delegates, then install from source. Or install the dev package.

Comment: Did you install the latest libheif? If not, then it may not work.

Comment: I tried again with the latest version of libheif. It is giving following error messages.
make[2]: *** [libheif_la-box.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libheif_la-heif_file.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libheif_la-heif_image.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libheif_la-heif.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Interrupt
make: *** [all] Interrupt
How can I solve these?

Comment: I used "$ make LDFLAGS=-no-undefined", the build went well but still, no HEIC extension is enabled.

Comment: The **ImageMagick** `configure` program that you run to create a Makefile is often not very good at finding other installed packages/delegates if you haven't got `pkg-config` installed first. Try installing `pkg-config` and then run your **ImageMagick** `./configure ... && make && make install` again.

Comment: Once you have `pkg-config` installed, it has an option that tells you all the packages it has config options for. Run that and check your `libheif` shows up. If it doesn't, you'll need to run something like `sudo find / -iname "lib*heif*.pc"` to find `libheif`'s `pkg-config` file and add its containing directory to your PKGCONFIGPATH environment variable and try listing known packages again till it finds it.

Comment: Back near a computer... you need `pkg-config --list-all` to find which packages it knows about.

Comment: And `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/directory/containing/libheif.pc`